# Java Slider and ProgressBar

Tags: java, jlabel, jprogressbar, jslider

I have two minor problems with a ProgressBar that I have connected to a Slider in a Java Frame I am working on. I am using NetBeans. I have added this code :

```
 private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {              
 JSlider source = (JSlider)evt.getSource() ;
 int value = source.getValue() ;
 jProgressBar1.setValue(value) ;}
```

1. As I move the slider, the ProgressBar moves with the movement of the Slider. However, it doesn't show any value in the Slider. I think with the code above I am setting to it do this, but it just moves and no value is printed in the progressBar. What is missing please?
2. This should be a really stupid simple question. The labels I have got under my Slider, is shown when i set the min/max from 0 - 5. When I set the min/max to 1 - 5, the label 1 is shown but 5 is NOT shown. What should I to see Labels 1 - 5 under a slider?

Comment: Did you set this on the JProgressBar    `progressBar.setStringPainted(true);` ?

Comment: Thanks. 

It worked with setting on the JProgressBar :
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

How can I solve the next problem please?

Comment: Btw, can I set the progressBar to show abolsute values 0-5 insead of percetange ones (0-100%) ? I would be nicer this way because I would like to use it for collecing rating.

Comment: Beside `jProgressBar1.setValue(value)` do this too `jProgressBar1.setString(String.valueOf(value));`

Comment: About your second problem you should edit your question and show us your code about the slider.

Comment: Very Nice, thank you very much ! With this (your answer):

Beside jProgressBar1.setValue(value) do this too jProgressBar1.setString(String.valueOf(value));

I am not gonna need labels under my lider so we can ignore that.

Comment: Slider allows you to pass a dictionary to specify the labels. See the section titled [Customizing Labels on a Slider, in the How to use sliders trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

Comment: How can I set your answer as the true answer , BatleHasmter?

Comment: I post an answer which summarize my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, you should set the `progressBar.setStringPainted(true);` on your progressbar, to show specific values in the progressbar add the following line:

```
jProgressBar1.setValue(value); 
jProgressBar1.setString(String.valueOf(value)); // this one
```

For more information check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) of the JProgressBar.